# speedtest-cli through brew on macOS Monterey 12.5 refusing to connect

Tags: macos, terminal, network, command-line, homebrew

I have `speedtest-cli 2.1.4b1` `brew` package installed on my mac. Before, it was working fine without any issues which kept me happy. However not too long ago I have noticed that every time I try to use it, I seem to always get `ERROR: Unable to connect to servers to test latency.`. *Can anyone shed some light on this?*

Decided to post this question because while searching online I did not find a similar one.

Comment: Did you try with different servers? Can you access those servers with curl/wget?

Comment: When I do `speedtest --list` I just get: `Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...` and that's it. Also, why I think it's the issue with this specific package is because for example `networkQuality -v` works fine. Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: It might be an access right issue, preventing brew-installed binaries from accessing the network.

Comment: Try temporarily disabling your firewall(Do not do this in public networks).